# Migrating custom core modules

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, admin, adminhtml, core-hacks

I could really use some help!

I was tasked with upgrading somebody's Magento installation from 1.7.x to 1.9.x. So, I installed Magento 1.9.x to a separate directory and copied over theme, skin, media, etc. All went fine and the site was up and running. That was until I discovered that some contact forms were missing from the upgraded site.

Upon further investigation, I figured that Admin panel in the new install was missing some tabs under *System -> Configuration -> General*. Those tabs seem to control the missing forms:

[image]

I started to dig dipper and noticed that corresponding modules were added under *app/core/code/Mage*. Here is what it looks like for the "Get a Quote" tab:

```
app/code/core/Mage/GetQuotes
app/code/core/Mage/GetQuotes/controllers/IndexController.php
app/code/core/Mage/GetQuotes/etc/adminhtml.xml
app/code/core/Mage/GetQuotes/etc/config.xml
app/code/core/Mage/GetQuotes/etc/system.xml
app/code/core/Mage/GetQuotes/Helper/Data.php
app/code/core/Mage/GetQuotes/Model/System/Config/Backend/Links.php
app/code/core/Mage/GetQuotes/sql/getquotes_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php
app/code/core/Mage/GetQuotes/sql/getquotes_setup/mysql4-install-0.7.1.php
app/code/core/Mage/GetQuotes/sql/getquotes_setup/mysql4-install-0.8.0.php
app/code/core/Mage/GetQuotes/sql/getquotes_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.7.1-0.7.2.php
```

I also noticed that extra code was added to *app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml* for each of the modules. Here is a section for "GetQuotes":

```
<Mage_GetQuotes>
   <active>true</active>
   <codePool>core</codePool>
   <depends>
      <Mage_Core/>
   </depends>
</Mage_GetQuotes>
```

So, naturally, I copied those modules and *Mage_All.xml* to the new install's directory structure, hoping that missing tabs would re-appear. But no such luck! What else did I miss? How can I add them back? I'm new to Magento and it's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

Hum i was wondering why do you use these folders for your custom modules ?
Why don't you put your files into app/code/local/YourNameSpace/GetQuotes and use a YourNameSpace.xml file in app/etc/modules/ ?

Comment: I don't know why it was done the way it was. I'm just trying to understand how I can recreate it. I know that it is considered a big "no-no" to modify the core Mage modules, but, maybe, some experts here had the experience or, at least, know how it's done in theory and will be able to point out where changes need to be made. I figured out some parts, but, obviously, some I missed.